# Drupal 6 and GlobalPayments HPP Integration

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, 3d-secure, global-payments-api

I wonder how to integrate 3DS2 in Drupal 6? I looked everywhere, everything I found is related to Drupal 7 or higher.

Somebody in Dublin wants us to upgrade their gateways to support HPP SCA. They used Realex as a gateway before, but it's no longer supported.

Now they're asking us to make a new gateway based on the GlobalPayments HPP SDK. We followed the steps and created a gateway, but when we tested it we got the 508 error:

> Invalid Data in MERCHANT_ID. Please contact the merchant.

I am not even sure if HPP is supported by Drupal 6 or not and they are convinced that there is no difference between Drupal 6 or 7, what works for Drupal 7 can work for Drupal 6 too.

Any idea?

Comment: My only suggestion is to get a D7 version running to sanity check against

Comment: @ChrisHaas unfortunately we can't upgrade to D7

Comment: I understand that. My suggestion is to install a fresh copy of D7 elsewhere, get that working with whatever you are trying to do, and then compare things. The error "Invalid Data in MERCHANT_ID" might literally be invalid data, and your code might actually be correct.

Comment: @ChrisHaas exactly, that's the only way we have now, we're working on it. But when I made researches, I couldn't find any result related to D6. As you said, we'll make sure first if the credentials are corrects and see what's next. Thank you